# Two requests for create one frontend?

Tags: javascript, python, frontend, backend

I try to create my service. I have endpoint with users and endpoint with data which are calculated on server side. When my website will up I want to presents all users and data. Front I write in React.JS (I am new in it) and in all examples I can see that always is one request. But can I make 2 requests on both enpoints for users and data? It is acceptable solutions? If not, how can I fix it?

Comment: Yes, you can either make two requests, or one endpoint that has all the data.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.state = {
users: [],
data: []
}

componentDidMount(){
  // ajax call for users -> response -> this.setState(users: res.users)

  // ajax call for data -> response -> this.setState(data: res.data)
}

render(){
  if(this.state.users.length === 0 && this.state.data.length === 0)
    return '' // <Loader />
  else{

    // do your stuff here

  }
```